# Problem with creating different sheets with names

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that separates rows into sheets by a certain column (column A).

Then all the rows that have the same value in the column will be placed in the a sheet named with the value (column A).

The separation works and all the rows that have same value are placed in the correct sheets.

The issue is that NOT all the sheets are named.

What I noticed is that names/values that have a similar name are the ones that fail to be named.

ie

```
Column           Sheet name
--------------------------------
blue car         blue car
blue par         sheet 1
red car          red car
red door         sheet 2
```

Code:

```
Sub wits_Create_sheet_by_column()
    Dim xRCount As Long
    Dim xSht As Worksheet
    Dim xNSht As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xTRrow As Integer
    Dim xCol As New Collection
    Dim xTitle As String
    Dim xSUpdate As Boolean
    Set xSht = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    xRCount = xSht.Cells(xSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    xTitle = "A1:O1"
    xTRrow = xSht.Range(xTitle).Cells(1).Row
    For I = 2 To xRCount
        Call xCol.Add(xSht.Cells(I, 1).Text, xSht.Cells(I, 1).Text)
    Next
    xSUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For I = 1 To xCol.Count
        Call xSht.Range(xTitle).AutoFilter(1, CStr(xCol.Item(I)))
        Set xNSht = Nothing
        Set xNSht = Worksheets(CStr(xCol.Item(I)))
        If xNSht Is Nothing Then
            Set xNSht = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            xNSht.Name = CStr(xCol.Item(I))
        Else
            xNSht.Move , Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End If
        xSht.Range("A" & xTRrow & ":A" & xRCount).EntireRow.Copy xNSht.Range("A1")
        xNSht.Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    xSht.AutoFilterMode = False
    xSht.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xSUpdate
End Sub
```

Comment: Be aware that there are limitations to the names of sheets (length, certain characters, etc.) Make sure that all the names comply with those rules.

Comment: @FDavidov I have looked into this and all the possible sheet names don't have special charaters.

Comment: Try to run your macro such that, instead of creating tabs and name them, it makes a list of the names that would be assigned to the new tabs. Once such a list is at hand, post the it here and I'll take a look.